# Relationship of system serial drivers to RS-232

Tags: drivers, serial, rs232

I am trying to strengthen my understanding of serial ports and device drivers.

I was told that the serial port standard, RS-232, defines the electrical characteristics and timing of serial port signals, the meaning of those signals, and the physical size and pinout of connectors.

It is also my understanding that all modern OSes have their own native serial device drivers for communicating (reading + writing) to serial ports.

So I guess I'm wondering what the relation is between RS-232 and these native OS serial device drivers. Do these drivers merely "implement" RS-232 on the PC-side? Or do the drivers and RS-232 "live" at two different "levels" of the serial communication stack/protocol? If so, how (exactly) are they different?

Comment: [UART controller or RS232 controller? Is UART a general word?](//stackoverflow.com/a/23310441)

Comment: The device driver talks to the physical hardware, which will be a controller for the RS232 port.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill (+1 for both) - so I *think* I'm hearing: (1) that the native (OS-provided) device driver's responsibility is to act as a controller/manager for the serial (RS-232) port, yes? And (2) that it is the responsibility of the device manufacturers to make sure that they're devices are RS-232 compliant so they can safely be connected to PCs?

Comment: The device driver is the interface between a program and the controller. The controller controls the port. Both sides or the physical port (the controller) and the attached device have to comply with the RS232 standard (otherwise it wouldn't work),